# No login screen : black screen

Tags: boot, login-screen

Hello and thank you for reading!

After and update, Ubuntu asked for a reboot. However after this reboot, I can't login anymore : I have a black screen with a black cross as a mouse cursor... <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> brings a flashing carret then after a minute or so a few errors :

```
timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxxxxxx
Dependency failed for /mnt/xxxxxxxxxxx
```

I didn't find much help online, but tried the nomodeset boot option, with same result.

In case this helps I recently plugged back one hard drive I had removed a while back, and I guess it's the first time Grub updates since that (actually I didn't see grub before, probably because there were no other boot options). But removing that drive doesn't change anything.

Comment: Your error message is a hard drive error. something failed to mnt

Comment: Do you think it could be my /home/ partition not loading (different drive than /)? Isn't it strange it happened during a reboot?

Comment: Maybe it was just time for the hard drive to die

Comment: @CGGJE if you can plug your hard drive into another machine, try running a SMART data test and see what comes up. It'll flag up if the hard drive has actually died unlike the unhelpful comment left by David here.

Comment: Don't know how to do that but I will dig into it. I realised that selecting the recovery boot option starts, so I can probably test it from the same computer. Thanks to both of you

Comment: @Maybe LB Did It : smartctl completed without error on both / and /home drives

Comment: @CGGJE `sudo apt install gnome-disks`if you don't already have it. Open `gnome-disks`, select the drive and then press the three dots or lines in the top right corner and press `SMART data & self test`. It will run a test on your drive and show you every result and whether any are a fail.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I booted from a liveusb, and reinstalled Ubuntu. I didn't format / nor /home so I didn't lose much at all.